# How to uninstall Ubuntu without replacing it with something else?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

My last day at work is tomorrow. I've had an Ubuntu 12.04 (laptop) system for several years and would like to completely remove the OS from the machine altogether. Since I'll be turning my laptop in to HR, I don't need/want to replace it with anything.

All the tutorials I've read involve a "drop-n-swap" method where you basically just install a new OS (Windows, etc.) over Ubuntu and essentially blow it out of your drive. But I don't want to do that. I want to strip the machine down to bare metal (BIOS, etc.).

Is this possible? If not, why, and what it my best next alternative? If it is possible, what are the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be use a liveCD and format the drive without reinstalling. You can do that with a normal Ubuntu Live CD just boot from it, then open a terminal and run

```
sudo gparted
```

Then delete the partitions you have defined and shutdown without installing. There you go, you now have an unpartitioned disk and a computer returned to a pristine state.

**Important**: If your objective is to stop anyone from gaining access to your files, you might want to go further than that. The above will make it *hard* for your data to be restored but not impossible. If you have nothing to hide and HR have no reason to spend hours and $$ looking into your data, this will be enough. If you are in paranoid mode and want to be *really* sure that the data are gone, you can use a program like `shred`. So, to shred all data on `/dev/sda1`, do:

```
shred -n 10 -vz /dev/sda1
```

For more details on `shred`, see [here](http://linuxg.net/shred-hard-drive-or-partition-in-linux-and-unix/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks @terdon. And the former is the case: I just want to remove the OS, not concerned at all about `shred`ding any data. But thanks for the tip on that anyways, good to know :-)

Comment: @TotesMcGotes: you may still want to consider to shred your drive. A full recovery of your previous OS including all your passwords and histories is only a matter of seconds if you had only removed the partition table with gparted.